# Disable single checkbox after ButtonSet is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

If I apply buttonset to a list of checkboxes using JQuery UI, how do i then disable a single checkbox from the list?

HTML

```
<div id="options">
    <input id="one" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="one">One</label>
    <input id="two" type="checkbox" value="2"/><label for="two">Two</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('#options').buttonset();
```

In the above example after buttonset is applied, I want to disable only checkbox with label `Two`.

### Edit

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paragnair/bvjfe/) for the above example. Just by adding attribute disabled does not help.

Comment: $('#two').attr('disabled', 'true');

Comment: Using $("#two").button("option","disabled", true); worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refresh the button widget after disabling the check box:

```
$("#two").prop("disabled", true).button("refresh");
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bvjfe/1/).

Comment: Thanks. Now my scenario has check-boxes rendering dynamically.. I will try to figure out a solution to disable the right check-box.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#two").attr("disabled", "disabled");
//OR
$("#two").attr("disabled", true);
```